# OpennSSH for windows: %u gives <domainname>/<username>

Tags: active-directory, openssh, sftp, windows-server, chroot

I'm using OpenSSH 8.1 for Windows and I'm trying to chroot users to their AD home dir [`D:\homes\sub\<username>`] using `%h` in the config file, however the chroot-directory redirects the user to `5UserProfile%`.

- I tried to use `D:\homes\sub\\%u` as the chroot-directory, but this redirects the user to `D:\homes\sub\<domainname>\<username>` which doesn't exist *(I think `%u` expands to the Windows NT/Prä Windows 2000 username)*

Is there any token for the pure username or another way to get users to chroot to their home directory?

Comment: Are you using Win32-OpenSSH or Cygwin?

Comment: I use Win64-OpenSSH